# Is this the simplest way to generate primes as a sum of two consecutive squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We start with looking for primes that can be expressed as a difference between two consecutive cubes which we write as $a^3-b^3=p$. (Here, we ignore the question of how many primes are there between two cubes). The difference between two cubes is obviously not always a prime. When it is, we can write $a^3-b^3=p$. Now $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)*(a^2 + b^2 + ab) = p$. Since a and b are consecutive integers ( $a>b$ ), then  we can drop the factor $(a-b)=1$. Now we have a simple expression to generate primes that are the sum of two consecutive squares. $q=p-ab=a^2+b^2$, where $q$ is a prime. It is also obvious that $q$ is not always a prime. Below are listed the primes $(P)$ generated as a difference between two consecutive cubes and then the primes $(Q)$ that are the sum of two consecutive squares.
We start with $3^3-2^3 = 19 = 3^2 + 2^2 + 2*3$. Then we simply subtract the product $2*3$ from $19$ to get $13 = 2^2 + 3^2$.
$P=(19,37,61,127,271,331,397,547,631...)$
and
$Q=(13,41,61,113,181,313,421,613,761,1013...)$.
A prime which is equal to a difference between two consecutive cubes does not always generate a prime that is the sum of two consecutive squares. But the number generated is of course always a sum of two consecutive squares.

Comment: That's why I used the word consecutive.

Comment: if $a=b+1$ then you are allowed to make it explicit in **all your formulas** what don't you understand with that ?

Comment: I edited the title back. I thought "squares" would have been a typo.

Comment: It won't make any difference. 13 will still be equal to 3^2 + 2^2. And 3=2+1. Now, if I am not seeing what you have in mind, please post all the details.

Comment: It should be much easier to consider $a^2+(a+1)^2=2a^2+2a+1$ and simply check for which $a's$, the expression gives a prime number.

Comment: @peter, if you do that, you lose the "obviousness" of a^2 and b^2 being two consecutive squares. I want it to jump at you. But I also started with looking at getting primes as a difference between consecutive cubes and I ended up with primes as a sum of two consecutive squares.